# Jetpack: Access visitor stats in templete

Tags: plugin-jetpack, statistics

is there any possibility to get the visitor number from my Jetpack-Plugin statistics?

I want to use it in my template to build a counter, which should be visible to all visitors.

I've been looking in the database, but there was nothing.

Comment: JetPack pulls the data from wordpress.com, so there should be an API. **Edit:** https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/#stats

Comment: I have a wordpress installation on my own server. Is there a possibility to access wordpress.com with my own URL?